# Can i find/filter element after $(this)?

Tags: jquery

in jquery we can find inner class or something else with

```
$("#id xxxxxx")
```

xx... can be anything.

But i am taking element by this like below:

```
$(".something").bind("click",function(){
  $(this).find("......
});
```

and want to take inner element something like : `$(this + " .divClassNameOrFilter")`

I can take the element with `$(this).find(".divClassNameOrFilter)`

But after i found something that will be an array and i can't continue with 
`$(this).find(".divClassNameOrFilter).css(.....`

I have to take the first element with `[0]` and wrap it again with `$(...)` like that:
`$($(this).find(".divClassNameOrFilter)[0]).css(.....`

Is there any way not to do like i said above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) like this:

```
$(this).find(".divClassNameOrFilter").eq(0).css(...);
```

Or use [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), like this:

```
$(this).find(".divClassNameOrFilter:first").css(...);
```

As an aside, there are other [filter functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering/) and [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/basic-filter-selectors/) as well.

Comment: @redsquare - Was I editing *while* you posted?  Not *based on it*, yes...I like my answer to be as complete as possible.  I'll always continue to add any relevant information to an answer *as I think of it*.  `:first` isn't an obscure selector I've never heard of, I *do* however like to post the link to the API when using functions/selectors, and it takes me a bit longer to edit since I do that.

Comment: first was enough for me but eq(x) is better than first to learn another method... Thanks...

Comment: it is fine. Nice context change to the comment above also. It was noted however.

Comment: @redsquare - That's what the edit icon is for...I'm sorry you think this answer got something from yours, that's not the case.  Did @patrick's original *also* copy yours? There's aren't many ways to solve this question, and anyone experience with jQuery can think of all of them off the top of their head.  The fact that 3 of the [top jQuery posters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=jquery&sort=stats&pagesize=50) came to the same conclusion is evidence of that.  Simple questions will *very often* have duplicate answers, since multiple people are answering simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

That should be possible using `.first()`:

```
$(this).find(".divClassNameOrFilter").first().css(.....
```